# How to use mock_model in spec_helper (for use with Authlogic)

Tags: rspec2

I'm upgrading to rails 3 and rspec 2.

I'm getting the error "undefined method `mock_model'" in my spec_helper. My current_user method sets up a mock user for authlogic and generates this error.

My spec helper looks like this

```
require 'authlogic/test_case'
require 'shoulda'
require 'helpers'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/factories/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
end

module LoginHelper
   include Authlogic::TestCase

   def login_user person
     activate_authlogic
     UserSession.create(...)
   end
end
include LoginHelper


def current_user(stubs = {})
  @current_user ||= mock_model("User", stubs)
end

def user_session(stubs = {}, user_stubs = {})
  @current_user ||= mock_model(UserSession, {:user => current_user(user_stubs)}.merge(stubs))
end

def login(session_stubs = {}, user_stubs = {})
  UserSession.stub!(:find).and_return(user_session(session_stubs, user_stubs))
end

def logout
  @user_session = nil
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[mock_model](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/mocks/mock-model) is defined in RSpec 2 in the `rspec-rails` gem. If you added `rspec-rails` to your Gemfile, then it should automatically be included for use with all the other necessary RSpec 2 gems.

You should also note that `mock_model` won't work with UserSession, as it inherits from `Authlogic::Session::Base`, not `ActiveModel`. You can use fix this by adding to your UserSession model:

```rb
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
end
```

Comment: I'm also receiving the same error. Gemfile does have `rspec-rails`, version is 2.6.4.

Comment: I found out what you said about not using mock_model on UserSession.  I ended up using double("UserSession") instead of changing the UserSession definition.  mock("UserSession") worked as well.